# TypeError: Cannot read property 'configure' of undefined in react-native

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, google-signin, react-native-ios

I am facing this issue while doing googleSignIn in Ios with react-native in android its totally working fine but in ios it is not. I also tried it with cocoapods but it's not working. I guess it is problem with linking but I followed the googlesignIn ios docs to implement it and also tried with unlink and link google signIn but it's not working. Please someone help me out.

[image]

below is the code for googleSignIn.

```
 componentDidMount() {
            this.unsubscriber = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((changedUser) => {
                // console.log(`changed User : ${JSON.stringify(changedUser.toJSON())}`);
                this.setState({ user: changedUser });
            });
            GoogleSignin.configure({
                iosClientId: '180169766571-2cfig8ri85cplmmdpnk2mcv0vb042055.apps.googleusercontent.com', // only for iOS
            })
            .then(() => {
                // you can now call currentUserAsync()
            });
        }

    onLoginGoogle = () => {
            GoogleSignin
              .signIn()
              .then((data)=> {
                  // create a new firebase credential with the token
                  const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(data.idToken, data.accessToken);
                  // login with credential
                  return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
              })
              .then((currentUser)=>{
                  console.log(`Google Login with user : ${JSON.stringify(currentUser.toJSON())}`);
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                  console.log(`Login fail with error ${error}`);
              });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use configure separately like this

```
componentDidMount(){
this.GoogleSignIn
}

GoogleSignIn = async () => {
    await GoogleSignin.configure({
        iosClientId:'key',
        offlineAccess: false,
    });
};
```